# Spring FactoryBean method with arguments

Tags: java, spring, configuration, annotations

I'm instantiating some beans by XML configuration and instance factory methods:

```
<bean id="galleryBeanFactory" class="de.tikron.webapp.gallery.bean.XmlGalleryBeanFactory" />

<bean id="pictureBean" factory-bean="galleryBeanFactory" factory-method="createPictureBean" scope="prototype" />
```

I instantiate my prototype beans programmatic by BeanFactory.getBean("bean", arguments...):

```
BeanFactory bf = ContextLoader.getCurrentWebApplicationContext();
PictureBean pictureBean = (PictureBean) bf.getBean("pictureBean", picture);
```

With Spring 3 I want to change to annotated java-based bean configuration. Here is my FactoryBean:

```
@Configuration
public class AnnotatedGalleryBeanFactory implements GalleryBeanFactory

  @Bean
  @Scope(BeanDefinition.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)
  protected PictureBean createPictureBean(Picture picture) {
    PictureBean bean = new PictureBean();
    bean.setPicture(picture);
    return bean;
  }
}
```

My Question: How can I pass parameters here? The code above results into org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [...model.Picture] found for dependency.

Comment: What's the relation between `PictureBean` and `Picture`? What class is a `FactoryBean`?

Comment: Picture is a persistence entity and PictureBean (maybe the name is a litte bit confusing) should be a wrapper for Picture providing additional methods.

Comment: I probably mixed up FactoryBean and factory method. For exercise I've implemented FactoryBean<T> now. But the same problem again: How can I pass arguments to the FactoryBean programmatically? Where will getBean(bean, args) pass them?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

With a bean definition like

```
@Bean
@Scope(BeanDefinition.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)
protected PictureBean createPictureBean(Picture picture) {
    PictureBean bean = new PictureBean();
    bean.setPicture(picture);
    return bean;
}
```

the bean definition name is `createPictureBean`. You can invoke it every time using [`BeanFactory#getBean(String, Object...)`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/BeanFactory.html#getBean-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object...-) like so

```
ApplicationContext ctx = ...; // instantiate the AnnotationConfigApplicationContext 
Picture picture = ...; // get a Picture instance
PictureBean pictureBean = (PictureBean) ctx.getBean("createPictureBean", picture);
```

Spring will use the arguments given (`picture` in this case) to invoke the `@Bean` method.

If you weren't providing arguments, Spring would try to autowire arguments when invoking the method but would fail because there was no `Picture` bean in the context.